# When was A.I.M. declared a sovereign nation?

Tags: marvel

In recent comics like *Avengers* and *Avengers Undercover* it is mentioned that A.I.M island is a nation and so the avengers can't attack them. When did this happen, is it explained in another comic, or did it just happen without explanation?

Comment: If A.I.M. screws the world with their androids, why can't Avengers attack them?

Comment: they have diplomatic inmunity ii is dumb but they can because is ilegal and they have proven nothing abut terrorist action from aim but htor can atack them because he is a god

Comment: That's a stupid plot-point. Latveria's sovereignty has routinely been violated by heroes in order to attack Dr Doom, the legal ruler of that nation-state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Marvel Wiki this happened (or was revealed) in Fantastic Four #610 http://marvel.wikia.com/Barbuda

> Barbuda was later sold to A.I.M. , where they decided to establish their own sovereign nation and become public.